# Show that $1^k+2^k+...+n^k$ is $O (n^{k+1})$.

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Show that $1^k+2^k+...+n^k$ is $O (n^{k+1})$.

So according to the definition of big-$O$ notation we have:

$$1^k+2^k...+n^k ≤ n(n^k) = n^{k+1}$$

whenever $n>1$

Is this a satisfied answer?  can someone help?

Comment: That's a fine answer.

Comment: If you just want big-O, then your answer is fine. If you want big-Theta (i.e. the sum is also lower bounded by $cn^{k+1}$ for some constant $c > 0$, that is a harder problem. Sometimes even professors confuse big-O and big-Theta, so make sure that all you have to do is big-O (upper bound).

Comment: I suppose it is big-$O$.

Comment: You know this thing is $\sim \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}$?

Comment: I have this exact same question, but don't understand this (def not saying it's wrong - only it's too concise for novice and I don't get it). How does this prove it? Explaining it like I'm 5yrs old would be welcomed.