# Show that $1^k + 2^k + ... + n^k$ is $\cal O(n^{k+1})$ , using an integral.

Tags: asymptotics

Let k be a positive integer. Show that $f(i) = 1^k+2^k+...+n^k$ is $O(n^{k+1})$.

Hi, I know that $f(i) ≤ \int\limits_{1}^{n+1}x^{k}dx$

When I integrate f(i) using this rule, I get
$\frac{((n+1)^{k+1}-1)}{(k+1)}$

How do I use this information to prove that $f(i)$ is $O(n^{k+1})$?

(the use of the integral is required for this problem by my teacher)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248679/show-that-1k2k-nk-is-o-nk1?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645160/show-that-1k2k-cdotsnk-is-omega-nk1?rq=1 ask the same question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k$ is $\Omega (n^{k+1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645160/show-that-1k2k-cdotsnk-is-omega-nk1?rq=1).